# user name and password are not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery

Folks, Please check my code..am executing the below code by http://localhost/mycart/login.php?is_ajax=1&username=srini&password=srini Then am getting this error even though passing valid user name and password. kindly help me thanks

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\wamp\www\mycart\login.php on line 25 and username 'srini' and password 'srini' not found

```
<?php

$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
if (isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax) {
       error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $uname = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $pword = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

    echo $uname;
    echo $pword;

     $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");

    if (!$con) {

        die('Connection Failed' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 = $uname AND L2 = $pword");
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0)
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "username '{$uname}' and password '{$pword}' not found";


mysql_close($con);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is probably `false`. Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 = '".$uname."' AND L2 = '".$pword."'");
```

Comment: Accepting an answer is a proper way of saying "Thank you" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` in your SQL query to mask string values:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE L1 = '" . $uname . "' AND L2 = '" . $pword . "'");`